# Understanding the split function of MLlib from PySpark

Tags: pyspark, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib

I have the following transformed data.

```
dataframe: rev

+--------+------------------+
|features|             label|
+--------+------------------+
|  [24.0]| 6.382551510879452|
|  [29.0]| 6.233604067150788|
|  [35.0]|15.604956217859785|
+--------+------------------+
```

When I split it into two set like following, I get something really unexpected. Sorry at first, I am new in PySpark.

`(trainingData, testData) = rev.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])`

Now when I check, I find:

```
trainingData.show(3)

+--------+--------------------+
|features|               label|
+--------+--------------------+
|  [22.0]|0.007807592294154144|
|  [22.0]|0.016228017481755445|
|  [22.0]|0.029326273621380787|
+--------+--------------------+
```

And unfortunately when I run the model and check prediction on test set, I get following:

```
+------------------+--------------------+--------+
|        prediction|               label|features|
+------------------+--------------------+--------+
|11.316183853894138|0.023462300065135114|  [22.0]|
|11.316183853894138| 0.02558467547137103|  [22.0]|
|11.316183853894138| 0.03734394063419729|  [22.0]|
|11.316183853894138| 0.07660100900324195|  [22.0]|
|11.316183853894138| 0.08032742812331381|  [22.0]|
+------------------+--------------------+--------+

Prediction and Label are in horrible relationship.
```

Thanks in advance.

Info Update:

Whole dataset:

```
rev.describe().show()

+-------+--------------------+
|summary|               label|
+-------+--------------------+
|  count|            28755967|
|   mean|  11.326884020257475|
| stddev|  6.0085535870540125|
|    min|5.158072668697356E-4|
|    max|   621.5236222433649|
+-------+--------------------+
```

And train set:

```
+-------+--------------------+
|summary|               label|
+-------+--------------------+
|  count|            20132404|
|   mean|  11.327304652511287|
| stddev|   6.006384709888342|
|    min|5.158072668697356E-4|
|    max|   294.9624797344751|
+-------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Seems like your Feature is invariant, so the prediction is equal to the intercept (bias). Do summary stats on features and look at your coefficients as well

Answer (score 0):

Try to set seed [pyspark.sql.DataFrame.randomSplit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.randomSplit)

```
(trainingData, testData)  = rev.randomSplit([7.0, 3.0], 100)
```

Comment: It actually create the same weird train and test sample. No luck. :(

Comment: I have updated the information on the question. Can you please, give some suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: What's your question or concern ?